# Como puedo hacer un programa que resuelva ecuaciones lineales ingresadas como cadena?

Tags: c

He logrado hacerlo de esta forma, pero hay una entrada distinta para cada valor y quiero que se pueda ingresar toda la ecuación en una misma cadena

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, x;

    printf("\nindique valor de a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nindique valor de b: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("\nindique valor de c: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("\nsu ecuacion es: %dx + %d = %d", a, b, c);
    x = (c-b)/a;
    printf("\nla solucion a su ecuacion es: %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola deberías de poner que lenguaje estas usando, usa las etiquetas para que lo demás podamos ayudarte, me imagino que es C o C++ , seguro a de haber una librería para que puedas leer ecuacuaciones

Comment: Ahí le puse una etiqueta xd es en C

Comment: Pide un string de números, separados por comas y lo validas

Comment: Y que hago con la 'x'? Son sistemas de ecuaciones. La 'x' puede estar en cualquier parte. Por eso dudo mucho que una simple validación lo solucione